# Transformer primary winding splitting

Tags: transformer, converter

[UCC2863x, High-Power Flyback Controller
with Primary-Side Regulation and Peak-Power Mode](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fucc28634)

In a design of a fly back converter the transformer used has 3 windings i.e. primary 328 μH and secondary and auxiliary windings and the primary winding has 54 turns but in the construction details the primary was split in two i.e. 27 windings each.

My doubt is should the primary windings have 4 pins on bobbin or just 2? The transformer guy used 3 pins for the primary. I have limited knowledge of transformers so if someone could help it would be great.

Comment: Might look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126006/center-tap-primary-coil-transformer) on EESE.

Comment: 2, 3 or 4 pins is basically down to how the guy decided to wind the transformer. I don't see why you have doubts?

Comment: It's not the pin position im concerned about but how many number of pins used for the primary.In the design there are two pins for the primary but in the transformer construction diagram the primary is split so the transformer guy used more than 2 pins. In my pcb i have used only two connection for primary.